NSLocalizedString in stringsdict not working with few key NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey
Hi I in my case NSLocalizedString not working with few key
.stringdict has below dict
but it works only one and other cases
<key>ticketPriceCount</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
  <string>%#@value@</string>
  <key>value</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
   <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
   <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
   <string>lld</string>
   <key>one</key>
   <string>%lld билет</string>
   <key>few</key>
   <string>%lld билета</string>
   <key>other</key>
   <string>%lld билетов</string>
  </dict>
 </dict>

